# SecurityFilterChain Bean with Basic Auth and Oauth support with latest version of Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I currently have a spring boot application that is secured with Oauth using the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class. Using this class I am able to secure the app with both basic authorization and `OauthResourceServer` support. But when I tried to use the `SecurityFilterChain` Bean I am only able secure the application with either basic auth or `OauthResourceServer`, depending on which is called last. This is how I am creating the bean:

```
     @Bean 
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception{
      http.csrf().disable();
     
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy( SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS );
                        if( this.credentials.isEnabled() ){
                            http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint( new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint() );
                        }
                        if( this.credentials.isOauthEnabled() ){
                            http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
                        }
                    return http.build();
}
```

Any suggestions or solutions will be appreciated.
(Edit) This is the logs after enabling TRACE logging

```
2022-08-17 10:11:27.112-0400 TRACE 10424 --- [           main] eGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer : Eagerly initializing {webSecurityConfigurer=<packagename>.WebSecurityConfigurer$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$942c15b4@4353230}
2022-08-17 10:11:27.620-0400 DEBUG 10424 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [authenticated] for any request
2022-08-17 10:11:27.639-0400 TRACE 10424 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
2022-08-17 10:11:27.641-0400 TRACE 10424 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
2022-08-17 10:11:27.651-0400  INFO 10424 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2b14628b, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7725470b, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@70c2a046, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@33ed6546, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@77c41838, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@548e70f0, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@318155b1, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@31d64d0f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@64657b13, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@63bb52ea, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5713e35f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@41dbf02b]
2022-08-17 10:11:27.749-0400 DEBUG 10424 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [authenticated] for any request
2
2022-08-17 10:11:27.749-0400 TRACE 10424 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
2022-08-17 10:11:27.754-0400  INFO 10424 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@56d4481f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@1f8e1096, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@17931cc0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@72499396, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@4283f29b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@4ce9985f, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@13a35d3b, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1cd93693, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@625430f8, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7a9e44ff, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6b9ce7a3, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@549dfe1d]
```

Comment: Is there any error? What does your request look like? Please provide more information so we can know exactly what is going on. Increase the logging level for Spring Security and check if the filters are being called: `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE`.

Comment: Yeah so basically in the code example above since I called .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt(); after httpBasic(), when I use basic auth I get a 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: Can you share your whole request?

Comment: I used postman but it is basically a POST request to rest endpoint, with Oauth client credentials token first which returns 200, and then using `Authorization Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz` which returns 401

Comment: In your piece of code, you have 3 opening curly braces and 4 closing curly braces. Are you sure the code is fine?